# I have a login form that I'm working on and I'm stuck. The code is supposed to login then open a new page but it is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

Here is my SQL Server stored procedure. I created three new parameters to pass in the login user id, username, and password

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Select_Logins]
    @Name_ID varchar(50),
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM Logins_2
    WHERE Name_ID = @Name_ID 
      AND UserName = @UserName 
      AND Password = @Password
END
```

This is the code behind. As shown, it goes into the database to get the logins data, then read it to verify the authentication of the logins entered by the user. If they match, it will open the index page, and if it does not it will display an error message. My program is skipping the first if statement and goes straight to the else statement.

```
try 
{
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlConnection connection;

    connection = new SqlConnection(constStringConnection);
    connection.Open();

    command = new SqlCommand("Select_Logins", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add("@Name_ID", UserIDtxt.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", UserNametxt.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password", Passwordtxt.Text);
                
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ("Username or password is invalid");
    }

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblMessage.Text = ("" + ex);
}
```

I thought I made a mistake with the database, but after recreating the database a couple times, I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not a pro on MS SQL Server, however, it looks as you generate a dynamic SQL statement in the procedure which is voluntary to SQL injection. Why do you create a procedure at all rahter than just executing a prepared statement? Furthermore it's a really bad idea to store plain passwords.

Comment: I have tried that as well and it does not work:                                                        
 command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Logins_2 WHERE Name_ID = @Name_ID AND UserName = UserName AND Password = @Password", connection);

Comment: How would you advise storing the passwords

Comment: Asides: Passwords should be _salted_ and _hashed_. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) You don't need to set the `Connection` twice in the `SqlCommand`, once in the constructor should suffice. The `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` should be in [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statements. Using a wildcard select list (`select *`) in a stored procedure that returns security information, or any information, seems inappropriate.

Comment: SqlCommand command;
                SqlConnection connection;

                connection = new SqlConnection(constStringConnection);
                connection.Open();

                command = new SqlCommand("Select_Logins", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@Name_ID", UserIDtxt.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", UserNametxt.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Password", Passwordtxt.Text);

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of code as a comment. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74972878/edit) your question to include the updated code.

Comment: I edited the code as proposed. I tried with Using but it did not work

Comment: Not really clear what your challenge is - put the data access code in a separate method from the redirect - the redirect should probably be in a controller method? Don't do `SELECT * 
    FROM Logins_2`  select specific columns and only those needed `SELECT ColumnName1, ColumnName2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use 'While reader'.. along with use of a counter instead of 'if reader...'?  If the counter = 0 then you can provide msg.

or...

Here's a link with example that may help:
[Link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types